# My auto generated id in sql looks like: 1, 101, 201.... How can i fix it?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm very beginner, I work on my own project, and I must add an id to all school subjects. But I want these id's showing on screen, and don't want to see: 1, 101, 201, 301.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "SUBJECTROWS", null);
    if (!rs.next()) {
        createStatement.execute("create table subjectrows(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,"
                                + "col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20))");
    }
} catch (...
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please post your database system used and the *full* reproducible code. `CREATE TABLE` alone generates no  `ID`s...

Comment: Please fully describe the problem, show the code used for inserting, and specify which database you are using. The problem sounds like you are using a pooled sequence with a step size of 100.

Comment: I think, i use JDBC:DERBY embedded database. Is that a database? Sorry, i'm very beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following in your statement 
`Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)`

Comment: I tried it, but nothing happens, the result is the same.